# add URL parameter in render method for liferay portlet

Tags: spring-mvc, url, liferay, portlet

I'm developing an MVC portlet using spring MVC. I want to add URL parameter to the URL of the opened page from the corresponding render mapping method.
 For example for this controller class:

```
@Controller(value = "SpringMvcController")
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
public class SpringMvcController {
    @RenderMapping
    public ModelAndView handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request,RenderResponse response,Model model) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView= new ModelAndView("view");
        /*What should I add here*/
        return modelAndView;

    }
}
```

I want to add some code in order when the view.jsp page is opened a parameter is added to the url like that **?param=value**

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this parameter from request, like that:

```
@RenderMapping
public ModelAndView handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse response, Model model) {
    HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil
            .getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest));
    String param = ParamUtil.getString(request, "param");

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't want to get url parameter, I want to add. If you take look in my example the rendermapping function  will open view.jsp page. So I want to add to the corresponding url of this page a parameter ?param=value

Comment: You can pass map of parameters in `ModelAndView` constructor or simply one parameter like: `new ModelAndView("view", "param", "value");`. Spring doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#ModelAndView-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-

Comment: Another solution: in `handleRenderRequest` add  `renderRequest.setAttribute("param", value);` then in jsp you can read this attribute like that `${param}`

Comment: If you are developing SpringMVC portlet you should use model object, set value of specific property of the model and then add object in your model and view object,eg. ModelAndView.addObject("yourModelName",modelObj), and then you can access the values inside jsp using jstl like ${yourModelName.propertyName}.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your parameters to your `ModelAndView` Object so you can access them in your `.jsp` file:

**Controller.java:**

```
@Controller(value = "SpringMvcController")
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
public class SpringMvcController {
    @RenderMapping
    public ModelAndView handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request,RenderResponse response,Model model) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView= new ModelAndView("view");
        modelAndView.addObject("objectName", object);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**SomeJspFile.jsp:**

```
...
<p>${objectName}</p>
...
```

If you create your own object and you create all Getters and Setter you even can access attributes of this object like this:

**SomeJspFile.jsp:**

```
...
<p>${objectName.attributeName}</p>
...
```